# Garbage storage, programming in C

Tags: c

I'm new programing in C. I have a main code with 781 lines that is out of control because garbage value is stored in vectors. A short part of the main code is shown below where it calls a subroutine called `diff_conv_intermedia1`.

```
diff_conv_intermedia1(&factorteta,&N,ID,DIFF,X1_intermedia,Y1_intermedia,X1C_intermedia,Y1C_intermedia,CU1_intermedia,CV1_intermedia,AW1_intermedia,AE1_intermedia,AS1_intermedia,AN1_intermedia,AP1_intermedia,Q1_intermedia,FXI1,FYI1,FI_intermedia1,1,2,1,1);

int q,w;
for(q=1;q<(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+1;q++)
 {
   for(w=1;w<(*N_Ptr)+1;w++)
 {
   printf("%lf\n",AP1_intermedia[q][w]);
 }
 }
```

So the subroutine shown below. When I print the results inside the subroutine, everything is OK, but when I print the results outside the subroutine, in the main code, garbage is stored in the vectors as `AP1_intermedia`. I don't know what could be wrong. I repeat the same procedure with other subroutines and I don't have any errors.

```
int diff_conv_intermedia1(int *factorteta_Ptr,
                          int *N_Ptr,
                          int ID,
                          double DIFF,
                          double X[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+1][*N_Ptr+1],
                          double Y[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+1][*N_Ptr+1],
                          double XC[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+2][*N_Ptr+2],
                          double YC[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+2][*N_Ptr+2],
                          double CU[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+1][*N_Ptr+1],
                          double CV[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+1][*N_Ptr+1],
                          double AW[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+1][*N_Ptr+1],
                          double AE[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+1][*N_Ptr+1],
                          double AS[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+1][*N_Ptr+1],
                          double AN[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+1][*N_Ptr+1],
                          double AP[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+1][*N_Ptr+1],
                          double Q[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+1][*N_Ptr+1],
                          double FX[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+1][*N_Ptr+1],
                          double FY[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+1][*N_Ptr+1],
                          double FI[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+1][*N_Ptr+1],
                          int WBC,int EBC,int SBC,int NBC)
{
int i,j;
double value,* valuePtr;
double AED, AWD, AND, ASD;
double AEC, AWC, ANC, ASC;
valuePtr = &value;

// Diffusive coefficients

for(i=1;i<(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+1;i++)
{
  for(j=1;j<*N_Ptr+1;j++)
{
  AWD = -DIFF*(Y[i][j-1]-Y[i-1][j-1])/(XC[i][j]-XC[i][j-1]);
  AED = -DIFF*(Y[i][j]-Y[i-1][j])/(XC[i][j+1]-XC[i][j]);
  AND = -DIFF*(X[i][j]-X[i][j-1])/(YC[i+1][j]-YC[i][j]);
  ASD = -DIFF*(X[i-1][j]-X[i-1][j-1])/(YC[i][j]-YC[i-1][j]);

  // Convection term
  if(ID==2)
    {
      max1_or_min2(CU[i][j-1],1,&value);
      AWC=-*valuePtr;
      max1_or_min2(CU[i][j],2,&value);
      AEC=*valuePtr;
      max1_or_min2(CV[i-1][j],1,&value);
      ASC=-*valuePtr;
      max1_or_min2(CV[i][j],2,&value);
      ANC=*valuePtr;
    }
  if(ID==1)
    {
      AWC =-CU[i][j-1]*(1.0-FX[i][j-1]);
      AEC =CU[i][j]*FX[i][j];
      ASC =-CV[i-1][j]*(1.0-FY[i-1][j]);
      ANC =CV[i][j]*FY[i][j];
    }

  // Set Coefficients matrix
  AW[i][j] = AWD+AWC;
  AE[i][j] = AED+AEC;
  AS[i][j] = ASD+ASC;
  AN[i][j] = AND+ANC;
  AP[i][j] = -(AE[i][j]+AW[i][j]+AN[i][j]+AS[i][j]);
  Q[i][j] = 0.0;

}
}
// West Boundary - Inlet B.C
for(i=1;i<(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+1;i++)
 {
  if(WBC==1) Q[i][1] = Q[i][1]-AW[i][1]*FI[i][0];
  if(WBC==2) AP[i][1] = AP[i][1] + AW[i][1];
  AW[i][1] = 0.0;

// East Boundary - (1)Dirichlet (2)ZERP-GRAD Outflow B.C
  if(EBC==1) Q[i][*N_Ptr] = Q[i][*N_Ptr] - AE[i][*N_Ptr]*FI[i][*N_Ptr+1];
  if(EBC==2) AP[i][*N_Ptr] = AP[i][*N_Ptr] + AE[i][*N_Ptr];
  AE[i][*N_Ptr] = 0.0;  
}

// South Boundary - (1)Dirichlet (2)ZERO-GRAD
for(j=1;j<*N_Ptr+1;j++)
{
  if(SBC==1) Q[1][j] = Q[1][j] - AS[1][j]*FI[0][j];
  if(SBC==2) AP[1][j] = AP[1][j] + AS[1][j];
  AS[1][j] = 0.0;

// North Boundary - (1)Dirichlet (2)ZERO-GRAD
  if(NBC==1) Q[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2][j] = Q[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2][j] - AN[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2][j]*FI[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+1][j];
  if(NBC==2) AP[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2][j] = AP[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2][j] + AN[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2][j];
  AN[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2][j] = 0.0;
}

// Print
int l,k;
for(l=1;l<(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+1;l++)
{
  for(k=1;k<*N_Ptr+1;k++)
{
  printf("%lf %lf %lf %lf\n",AP[l][k],AS[l][k],AN[l][k],FI[l][k]);
}
}

return 0;
}
```

If anybody wants I can send all code, but have many extensions.

Comment: The fact your program produces garbage is not justifying the `garbage-collection` tag.

Comment: It is unlikely you will get a satisfactory answer to the question in the form it is written. It's a loads of unreadable code without clear problem definition and without clear test cases.

Comment: @Catalina V Do you realize that array indices start from 0?

Comment: Quite often when I hear that it prints fine within a function, but not without, it usually means you are returning a local function object by reference instead of passing the reference in or returning by value.  Check your return values.

Comment: @@Catalina V Why is parameter factorteta_Ptr declared as a pointer?

Comment: Is this ported FORTRAN77 code?

Comment: @hyde I'm using Emacs to edit the code, but to paste the code maybe the format change. I know is very difficult to understand because the code is very large and this is just a part. But thank you

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I know that indices start from 0, I just need only from 1

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Thanks. I do not know much about programming but I think that's what is happening. Every vector is declared in the main code and I suppose the vectors are stored as pointers and do not have to change. I checked all return values and I do not have problems with other vectors, only with this

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I had problem in other code part using the factortheta value so I used a pointer because this value was changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function declaration:
`double AP[(*factorteta_Ptr)*2+1][*N_Ptr+1]`

I don't quite think this is doing what you think it is doing.  While I haven't seen something like this myself before, I believe that this is telling the compiler to create a variable length 2D array for you based on the other given parameters.  Then, you fill in these values in your function.  But, because you don't return this value nor do you declare it as pass by reference, it is thrown away when you return, thus the work is lost and you have garbage in your array in `main()`.  Better form would be to create this array in `main()`, then pass it in by reference something like `double *AP[][]`, or return this array upon exit, or hack things up even worse than this function and just make it a global so that you can see it anywhere.

Comment: I understand what you say and will consider your suggestion. I think I have to study a little more about this topic.